# Активация класса active при нажатии на ссылку

Tags: bootstrap

Как сделать так, чтобы ссылка Home была active так как показано в коде.

Вот код:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav - вот например нажимаешь на кнопку Profiles и она становиться active.

Comment: Честно говоря не понятно, чего вы хотите и что у вас не получается...
Проверьте подключили ли вы js и css файлы bootstrap`а.

Comment: Скорее всего это делается с помощью JQuery. Нужно удалить класс active и присвоить следующему по нажатию.

Comment: Это все уже реализовано в bootstrap.js подключите его только.
Перечитайте мануал по установке бустрапа.